# How do I launch Maps intent with label and sub-label?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have an intent picker in my app. When the user selects Google Maps, I want to set the title and subtitle in the maps.

[image]

How do I get the subtext set in Google Maps?
I looked at the api(https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) and I used

> geo:0,0?q=lat,lng(label)

But I can only set the title text(label) using this. How do I set the subtitle?
I want to do it only using common intent for location and not just Google Maps.